# Are worldlines/geodesics coordinate/frame independent

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, geodesics

My professor states in the lecture that geodesics are frame independent.

But to me geodesics are just special type of wordlines and worldlines aren't coordinate or frame independent. In the rest frame of the particle the worldline on the Minkowski diagram would be along the time axis but in a moving frame they wouldn't be.

Even a geodesic of a free particle would be a straight line in inertial (cartesian or polar coordinates) but in a rotating or accelerating frame they wouldn't be straight lines.

So why did my professor state that geodesics are frame/coordinate independent.

**Will the geodesics/worldlines be (look like ) the same in all (inertial or accelerating or whatever) frames (coordinate system).**

Is my understanding wrong. Is what I have said above not correct or does the professor mean something else.

Comment: A geodesic is always a straight line *locally*. How you plot it in your coordinates is a different matter. I think that is what your professor is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean here.  I'm fairly certain that what your instructor meant was that **whether** a worldline is or is not a geodesic is a frame-independent notion.  This is because geodesics $\gamma$ extremize the path length functional:
$$S[\gamma] = \int d\lambda \sqrt{ g(\dot \gamma,\dot \gamma)}$$
Nothing in the definition of $S$ requires a choice of coordinates, so whether $\gamma$ extremizes $S$ or not doesn't depend on your choice of coordinates.

A different way to see this is to note$^\dagger$ that geodesics are solutions to the autoparallel equation
$$\nabla_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma = 0$$
which is a tensor equation, so once again coordinate-independent.

Of course, the *coordinates* of the points along that worldline will clearly depend on which coordinate chart you use.

---

$^\dagger$This assumes that you have chosen the Levi-Civita connection, which we typically do in GR.

Comment: So a curved/straight worldline (in SR or GR) in one frame/coordinates would be curved/straight (drawn) differently in another coordinate/frame. And  this holds for geodesics too. **The same solutions of geodesic equation when drawn using one coordinate/frame would be (say a straight line in this coordinate/frame) would be **drawn** differently if drawn using another coordinate/frame ( maybe a curved line in this coordinate/frame). Is this understanding **correct**. Please let me know this. And what I understood that the lecturer meant lthat a geodesic **would** be a geodesic in any frame.

Comment: While letting me know what I have said above is correct or not please read **"SEEN as or drawn as"** where ever I have just written "drawn as".

Comment: The descriptor "straight" in this context means "autoparallel" - that is, $\nabla_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma =0 \implies \ddot \gamma+ \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho} \dot \gamma^\mu \dot \gamma^\rho = 0$.  If that is what you mean, then yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Maybe, I can be more precise. Suppose, in GR, I solve the geodesic equation in some frame. I get a solution, say a parabola(so in those coordinates, the plot would be a parabola/ see the particle moving in parabola). No I try to solve the geodesic equation in another frame(an accelerated one). Then in this new frame will I get a parabola again or some other curve( so plotting the solution in this new frame will be a parabola or some other curve). Please let me know this. I am thinking it should be another curve because **worldlines depend on the coordinates you plot them in**. Is that correct.

Comment: cont.. -worldline of a particle at rest would be parallel to the time axis but the worldline of the same particle in another moving frame wouldn't be parallel to the time axis. It would have changed. And geodesics are just a special kind of a worldline. I am thinking along these lines. So I said the geodesic which is a parabola in one frame shouldn't be a parabola in another frame/coordinates. Is this wrong...

Comment: @Shashaank The **coordinates** of a worldline depend on which coordinates you use to plot them.  This is trivially true.  But a worldline is a smooth curve on the spacetime manifold, which exists independently of any coordinate system.  Moving from coordinate system to coordinate system will change your drawing - after all, a circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in cartesian coordinates is a straight line $r=1$ in polar coordinates - but the *geometrical* properties of a curve (e.g. whether or not it is a geodesic, whether or not it is timelike, etc) are independent of any coordinate system.

Comment: Sorry your example looks to be wrong. $x^2+y^2=1$ is a circle in Cartesian and $r=1$ is **also a circle in polar**. The eqn of straight line in polar would be $\frac{1}{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}$. I do understand that geodesic in 1 frame would be a geodesic in another one. What I'm saying is that the geodesic eqn of a particle in some frame solves out to be a parabola ($y^2=4ax$)but solving the geodesic eqn for the same particle in another frame **gives another curve, not a parabola ($y=f(x)$**). In you example both $x^2+y^2=1$ and $r=1$ plot out to be circles. Is your example wrong...

Comment: @Shashaank [Let's continue this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117920/discussion-between-j-murray-and-shashaank).

Comment: okay I have joined. I have tried to explain the question there and what I am thinking. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Hello, hope you remember we had a bit of discussion regarding this in chat. I wanted to discuss a bit about https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/603253/113699 ( particularly how coordinates are assigned in FLRW metric). I couldn't ping you on chat. It said the chat is frozen. I was confused on this topic for a while. Couldn't precisely figure out a way, hence thought to ping you. Would you like to discuss or help me a bit in it.

Comment: @Shashaank I've opened a chat here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118602/room-for-j-murray-and-shashaank

Answer (score 2):

The statement you have attributed to your professor is not very rigorous on its own. It is trying to address a common source of confusion amongst students.

Imagine a world without coordinates first. Say you have a ball moving in absence of any forces. GR tells us that it will move along a straight line through spacetime. In the frame attached to the ball there is no motion in space. Time passes uniformly as $\tau$ (proper time). The change in its four velocity ($\mathbf{u}$) with respect to proper time is $\mathbf{0}$ as this ball is a free particle. The following is thus its geodesic equation:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \mathbf{0}
$$

Now you sitting somewhere else record this ball's position in space as a function of time. You are therefore introducing a coordinate system. The ball is still moving in a straight line but your coordinate system could be flat or curved depending upon the energy-momentum distribution.

Take a non GR example before we attempt to formalize this further. Imagine an airplane flying the shortest distance from A to B. If you zoom in sufficiently (in other words, just look locally and in formal terms look in the infinitesimal subspace around the plane's position at any point on its trajectory) the velocity vector is parallel to the trajectory. Which implies no change in trajectory. If you now plot this over a globe you get a great circle. If you plot this on Mercator projection you get a strange curve.

[image: Geodesics on a 3-d sphere]

Formally, if your coordinate basis is given by $\mathbf{e}_\alpha$ and $\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}$ are the Christoffel symbols for your coordinate system then you can simplify the geodesic equation using the chain rule as follows:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}^\alpha \mathbf{e}_\alpha}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \mathbf{u}^\alpha \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{e}_\alpha}{\mathrm{d}\tau} + \mathbf{e}_\alpha \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}^\alpha}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \mathbf{u}^\alpha \Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha \beta} \mathbf{u}^\beta \mathbf{e}_\gamma + \mathbf{e}_\alpha \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}^\alpha}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \mathbf{u}^\alpha \Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha \beta} \mathbf{u}^\beta \mathbf{e}_\gamma + \mathbf{e}_\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}^\gamma}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \mathbf{0}
$$

Rearranging you get the geodesic equation in the coordinate form.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}^\gamma}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = - \Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha \beta} \mathbf{u}^\alpha \mathbf{u}^\beta
$$

Quite clearly, this is a frame dependent equation. But on its own the geodesic is still unchanged. How you *plot* it has changed.

Comment: This a very nice answer, thus the upvote. So if a geodesic in one frame  is **(drawn as or seen as**) one curve (say a straight line or any other curve) then if it is drawn or seen in another coordinate/frame, then it will a **different curve**. This statement is correct.  Let me know this, please. I understood that a geodesic **would be** a geodesic in any frame just that it will be drawn or seen differently in different frames. Is this understanding correct. Please let me know this.

Comment: When you say " The ball still moves in a straight line.... " . But worldlines for the same particle are different in different frames. In a rest frame the worldlines would be parallel to time axis but in a moving inertial frame it won't be.

Comment: @Shashaank you are right in your first comment in that if a particle is moving on a geodesic (formally, its trajectory satisfies the geodesic equation) in one frame then it will satisfy the geodesic equation in all other frames. The shape of the curve will of course depend on the observer. When I say the ball moves in straight line, I mean straight as defined for that coordinate system and when viewed *locally* (i.e., in the infinitesimal subspace at any point in spacetime). There is no requirement for unaccelerated particles to move in straight lines in GR when you zoom out.

Comment: So that means if I solve (GR) the geodesic equation in one frame , I will get  a curve, say a parabola. That is I will see that particle move in a parabola ( I will plot a parabola). Now if another observer, in another frame (say an accelerated one etc) observes that particle then will not see the particle as moving in a parabola, but he will plot another curve for the particle which will nit be a parabola. Is that right. The solution to the geodesic eqn was a parabola in one frame and will something different. If that is correct why do we say geodesics on a sphere are circles.

Comment: They will be circle in one frame and another curve in another coordinate

Comment: @Shashaank I think we should move this discussion to a chat. But to give a quick answer --when we say geodesics on a sphere are a great circle we have already specified a coordinate system (sphere in this case). If someone then chooses a different coordinate system then will get a different shape.

Comment: Sure we can continue to the chat section. Can you please send the link, I don't how to generate a chat link. But before going there could you just tell me whether what I have said in the **2nd last** comment(about the solution being parabola in one frame and some other curve in another frame) is correct. Maybe if you can just let me know if what I have said there is totally correct then I guess it will be all clear. I think I am getting your point specifically by what you have written in the your last comment. A confirmation of what I have written (about the parabola thing) will work

Comment: @Shashaank Yes. That part is correct. What you have to keep in mind is that these "curves" are an observer's description of a particle's worldline and there is no reason to expect that they will generate same shapes for different observers.

Answer (score 0):

The way physicists generally talk is that things like scalars, vectors, and tensors are classified according to their transformation properties. However, it's understood by the people talking this way that there is an equally valid point of view in which something like a momentum vector is an invariant quantity, but its components have transformation properties that depend on what coordinate system you pick.

> Even a geodesic of a free particle would be a straight line in inertial (cartesian or polar coordinates) but in a rotating or accelerating frame they wouldn't be straight lines.

Changing the coordinates doesn't change whether it's curved. A solution to the geodesic equation is still a solution regardless of the coordinates you use.